# Javascript Memory Leak Troubleshooting

Tags: javascript, memory-leaks

I'm working on a pretty simple web application that displays top users hitting a web page. I've written some code in d3 to convert the data to a bar graph and have written a simple php script to pull the data from a database. I use an ajax request to pull the data once every 5 seconds and update the bar graph. Without fail if I leave the page open in the background it will get to the point of the old

```
aw snap google chrome has run out of memory
```

I've gone through a bunch of sites on memory leaks and done what I could to prevent them but there is a decent enough chance I messed something up. The problem is other than that error coming without fail on this page (and I've written plenty of javascript applications where this doesn't happen) there is absolutely no evidence the leak is happening. The data I'm retrieving every 5 seconds is 212kb, and when I do a heap recording heap memory peaks at 25mb and doesn't really increase (it generally bounces between 10 and 25mb), so it seems like that 212kb is being garbage collected and is not accumulating in the heap. Similarly I've looked at the task manager and when I make that the only tab open there seems to be a good amount of fluctuation but definitely not a trend upwards. I've taken heap snapshots and they tend to be in the 10-15mb range and I really don't understand how to read the snapshot, but here's what it looks like after running for 15 minutes or so:

[image: heap snapshot]

It's just getting extremely frustrating, I've spent 20-30 hours on this but it seems like a case of a watched pot never boils. If I look for evidence of it happening I can never find any, but if I leave it open while I leave my computer for a few hours, without fail the page crashes. It's almost like the garbage collector just waits for me to leave my computer before deciding to just stop running.

Any thoughts on what could be the culprit here or next steps to attempt to identify the culprit? This is my first experience with a memory leak and it's driving me crazy. Thanks.

Comment: line 37 of your code looks suspect

Comment: I mean would it actually help to post my code? This was more a general question about memory leaks and whether memory leaks outside the heap were a thing, or whether I was missing a way to see it occurring. I wouldn't expect stackoverflow to comb through a ton of code and solve my memory leak for me.

Comment: I was being flippant ... but a single snapshot is pointless ... two snapshots could be more useful :p oh, and another thing ... have you tried a different browser? perhaps it's a general chrome issue, in which case you've wasted 20-30 hours debugging a browser issue!!

Comment: just a guess, but this *sounds like* you are allocating new variables for your data each iteration of the ajax call, and never destroying / re-using the existing variables.  This can take *quite a long time* to manifest, but I would start with looking for a type in the stack heap that continually grows in object count.

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/laYJMvW.png is a second snapshot, it's 12.3mb

Comment: @zachvac us combing through your code to help you find a memory leak is exactly something we are happy to do, assuming you have done lots and lots of work to try and fix the stuff yourself beforehand, which it seems you have. Definitely post the relevant code :) (If it's a lot, maybe get a working codepen or similar example running)

Comment: just between those screenshots, there were about 200 `(array)` elements allocated.  I don't know the time frame between those screenshots, but that could eventually grow to a massively large amount.

Comment: Without an example that displays your issue, this is probably off-topic as too broad. Try to produce a minimal example, or at least work out which part of the code is causing the leak (I don't know why this phenomenon is called a "leak", it's more like flooding to me). ;-)

Comment: hmm it does seem like the number of (array) objects is getting bigger and bigger. Drilling down shows a bunch of different types of things for example (at)230011, (script line ends)[] (at)337501, (transition array)[] (at)415487, etc. Drilling into those shows more things that I don't particularly understand. Replaced the at symbol with (at) because it was trying to tag users.

Comment: so definitely seeing the code for your ajax call will be important here.

Comment: Is there a way for me to post code here? It's a pretty low character limit for comments and not sure how to format code in a comment.

Comment: ok so now the memory in the task manager for chrome (still only one tab) is 1.1 gigs, but I just took a heap snapshot and it's 14mb. I did a heap timeline (for 20 seconds) and the max was 22.1mb. All memory in my application should be on the heap right? This is just bizarre.

Comment: oh nvm I'd taken so many snapshots that was taking all the memory lol

Comment: ok so I just logged on (~1 hour since it initially loaded). Now I can't right click chrome and my app is unresponsive and the memory is increasing at something like 10mb per second when I open task manager. Any idea why it would stay steady for so long then explode like that? Any way to see what was happening at this time given I can't open the debug tools and it's probably about to go to the "aw snap" page?